# Onchange com duplo valor

Tags: javascript, html

É possível pegar numa combobox os valores de cada `option`? Algo parecido com isto:

```
<form action=""> 
<select name="customers" onchange="Publicidades(this.value, 0)">
    <option value="" id="teste">Escolha o utilizador</option>
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
<select name="customers" onchange="Publicidades(0,this.value)">
    <option value="" id="teste">Escolha a localidade</option>
<?php echo $options_1; ?>
</select>
</form>
```

No primeiro *select* onde tem 0 ia buscar o valor do *select* de baixo e no segundo select onde tem 0 ia buscar o valor do select de cima.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, pois não me parece ter ligação alguma com PHP. Use as tags relevantes a pergunta e snippets são obviamente para reproduzir exemplos de problemas com CSS/HTML/JS e nada mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi a sua duvida, você quer trocar o `0` em `Publicidades(this.value, 0)` e `Publicidades(0,this.value)` pelo valor atual do outro select.

Para isto você pode usar usar propriedades como:

- `document.getElementById` (pela apenas um elemento com ID, ex: `<select id="foo">` e `document.getElementById("foo")`)
- `document.getElementsByClassName` (pela todos elementos a classe, ex: `<select class=" test foo ola">` e `document.getElementsByClassName("foo")`)
- `document.querySelector` usa seletores avançados para pegar um elemento
- `document.querySelectorAll`usa seletores avançados para pegar vários elementos

> Uma dica, não vejo a necessidade de `id` dentro um option, acho que você queria adicionar ao select na verdade. Eu também não entendi por que repetiu o atributo `name="customers"`, mas talvez as sua ações não tenham a ver com um formulário

Ao invés de usar a propriedade `onchange` diretamente no html, você pode setar usando Javascript, por exemplo:

```html
<select id="foo-1">
   <option value="">Selecione...</option>
   <option value="olá mundo!">olá mundo!</option>
   <option value="Hello world!">Hello world!</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById("foo-1").onchange = function() {
    alert(this.value);
};
</script>
```

No seu caso, você está usando dois selects, então faça algo como:

```html
<form action=""> 
    <select name="customers" id="customers-A">
        <option value="">Escolha o utilizador</option>
        <option value="a 1">a 1</option>
        <option value="a 2">a 2</option>
        <option value="a 3">a 3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="customers" id="customers-B">
        <option value="">Escolha a localidade</option>
        <option value="b 1">b 1</option>
        <option value="b 2">b 2</option>
        <option value="b 3">b 3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var a1, a2;

    function Publicidades(a, b) {
        alert([a, b]);
    }

    a1 = document.getElementById("customers-A");
    a2 = document.getElementById("customers-B");

    a1.onchange = function() {
        Publicidades(a1.value, a2.value);
    };

    a2.onchange = function() {
        Publicidades(a2.value, a1.value);
    };
</script>
```

Se estiver usando jQuery, você pode fazer assim:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
    $("#result").html([a, b].join(","));
}

$(document).on("change", "#customers-A", function() {
    foo(this.value, $("#customers-B").val());
});

$(document).on("change", "#customers-B", function() {
    foo(this.value, $("#customers-A").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>

<form action=""> 
    <select name="customers" id="customers-A">
        <option value="">Escolha o utilizador</option>
        <option value="a 1">a 1</option>
        <option value="a 2">a 2</option>
        <option value="a 3">a 3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="customers" id="customers-B">
        <option value="">Escolha a localidade</option>
        <option value="b 1">b 1</option>
        <option value="b 2">b 2</option>
        <option value="b 3">b 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Para concluir, você pode usar qualquer um dos métodos citados anteriormente ( (`document.getElementsByClassName`, etc) ou jQuery, há mais de uma maneira de se fazer as coisas.